# Mininet 2.2.1 not generating any packetIn messages for openVswitch 2.5.0

Tags: mininet, openvswitch

Recently I have upgraded openVswitch from 2.1.2 to 2.5.0, but there are no trafic generation(packetIn) after this upgrade with mininet 2.2.1.

It was working for mininet2.2.1 and openVswitch2.0.2 earlier.

Using below command:

sudo mn --topo linear --mac --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13 --controller remote,ip=,port= --ipbase=2.2.2.0/24

Would it compatibility issue between ubuntu and ovs?

Could you please advise me what to do ?

cheers, Manju

Comment: which version of ubuntu you are using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04. Later I found ovs2.5.0 compatible with ubuntu16.04.